# WooCommerce product permalink changed

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic

my product structure was like the following before:

https://example.com/producto/product-name/

Now, I've done some updates to the translations and this is how the product urls appear now:

https://example.com/product/product-name/

(without the 'o' in product)

It's actually OK to me, but on my shop page the URLs kept the final 'o', redirecting to 404 my products. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest and best way to do that is to edit your **.htaccess** file.

Your .htaccess file is located in your FTP under the folder public_html (usually).

This way, when a user is trying to access your old url /producto/
it will immediately change to /product/ as a 301 permanent redirect.

In that file, you will see these lines-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

After those line, try adding this line-

```
RewriteRule ^producto/(.*) product/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I didn't test this code but i believe it should do the trick

Comment: Thanks! Actually I found another solution: rewriting the product URL structure through the permalink panel.